Unrolling a loop to iterate through 64-bits, 32-bits at a time
I'm running a relatively simple 64-bit heavy algorithm on a 32-bit Tensilica Xtensa DSP microcontroller, and profiling shows that we're spending a good fraction of our time doing basic 64-bit operations on the two 32-bit CPU registers of a 64-bit variable.
for(uint64_t bit = 1; bit; bit<<=1){
    if(bit & aGlobalBit){
         //Some light math
    } else {
        //different light math
    }
}

Sparsely unrolling the above pseudocode twice, covering bit indexes 0->31 and 32->63 separately, shows a large runtime speedup. Disassembling shows a large reduction in instructions per loop, as GCC12 works out that only half of a uint64_t is in use for each loop:
//Do32LSBs
for(uint32_t bit = 1; bit; bit<<=1){
    if(bit & aGlobalBit){
         //Some light math
    } else {
        //different light math
    }
}
//Do32MSBs
for(uint32_t bitMsb = 1; bitMsb; bitMsb<<=1){
    uint64_t bit = (uint64_t)bitMsb << 32;
    if(bit & aGlobalBit){
         //Some light math
    } else {
        //different light math
    }
}

But I'd like to find a cleaner way to do this - iterating the bits in a uint64_t is used a lot, and the speedup isn't worth maintaining two copies of the loop body. I've read the GCC compiler manual section on inlining and there isn't an option to do it sparsely. How can I wrap up the bit-iteration abstractly so I can write it once and use it with for-auto-x ? If not, is there a another way to abstract the iteration from the loop body, while still allowing the iteration to proceed 32-bits at a time per uint64_t?

aGlobalBit -- if this thing is really global, perhaps even a volatile register, the compiler will not optimize this loop in any way, because it can't. Start with uint64_t const myLocalBit = aGlobalBit; and see if that helps. Even when splitting, read this thing once uint32_t const msb = aGlobalBit >> 32; instead of repeating that in every loop. That's also IMHO easier to read and understand for humans.

I double-checked that there are no function calls or aliasing possible in the loop body, so the compiler is quite free to optimize and reorder. Moving aGlobalBit to a function parameter didn't materially change the iteration instructions.

Perhaps a nested loop that specifies the additional offset in the outer loop might be enough to get the compiler doing what it should?
for(const uint32_t adjust : {0, 32}) {
    for(uint32_t bitbase = 1; bitbase; bitbase <<= 1){
        uint64_t bit = (uint64_t)bitbase << adjust;
        if(bit & aGlobalBit){
             //Some light math
        } else {
            //different light math
        }
    }
}

Given the target architecture, I can't really test this myself, but it's the least ugly approach that might work.
